# making unit test binaries using scons with g++ and gtest

Tags: c++, g++, scons, googletest

I am not able sucessfully build the the project using scons, g++ and gtest. I want to use gtest as unit test. My project looks like below:

```
  project 
     | -SConstruct
     | -src
          | -name.hh
          | -name.cc
          | -main.cc
     | -gtest 
          | -/src/gtest_name.hh
          | -/src/gtest_name.cc
          | -/src/gtest_main.cc
```

Inside SConstruct for project building, I have following code:

```
 program_srcs = ['name.cc']
 cpppath      = ['./src']
 libpath      = ['.', 'path_to_third_party_lib']
 libs         = ['thirdlib']

 pro_env = Environment()
 env.Append(CPPPATH = cpppath)
 env.Append(LIBS = libs)
 env.Append(LIBPATH = libpath)
 env.Library('name', program_srcs)

 libpath.append('name')
 env.Append(LIBPATH = libpath)
 env.Program(target = 'NAME', source = [ './src/main.cc']

 test_src = ['./gtest/src/gtest_name.cc']
 test_env = Environment()
 test_env['LIBPATH'] = ['.']  
 test_env.Program("unit_test", test_src, LIBS=['name'])
```

Inside gtest_name.cc

```
include"name.hh"

TEST_F(TESTNAME, testmethod) {
    Name name;
    ASSERT_EQ(name.get_surname, "MIKE");
}
```

When I tried to compile and build, it gave following errors for gtest.

```
 g++ -o gtest/src/gtest_name.o -c gtest/src/gtest_name.cc
 gtest/src/gtest_name.cc:10:29: error: name.hh: No such file or directory
```

When I checked for library 'name', it was already constructed. Could you please tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the required include search path "src" to the variable CPPPATH, for the environment "env".
But you build the library with the environment "test_env" which doesn't have CPPPATH defined.
That's why the "-I" directive is missing in your compiler call.

Note, that SCons offers a Clone() method for environments. It copies over all current definitions (and builders for example) from one environment to create a new one...this might come in handy here.